# Repeating task value not setting

Tags: c#, .net

The code I have:

```
static Timer checkTask;

public override void AwakeFromNib()
{
    base.AwakeFromNib ();
    checkTask = new Timer(2000);
    checkTask.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(updateEvent);
    checkTask.Enabled = true;
    count.StringValue = "initial"
}

private void updateEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e){
    String URLString = "http://example.com/stat/data.xml";
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader (URLString);

    while (reader.Read()) 
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType) 
        {
        case XmlNodeType.Text:
            count.StringValue = "updated";
            Console.WriteLine ("This code was reached!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I used some example values for "count" to help describe the issue.
When I do the following in the "AwakeFromNib()" call:

```
count.StringValue = "initial";
```

The string value is set and all is well. 
However IF i do the same thing in "updateEvent()", the string is never set and remains as "initial". Why is this happening?

The console write shows up every 2 seconds.

Comment: In `updateEvent` method, you have the line `count.StringValue = "updated";` in switch case `XmlNodeType.Text`. That executes only when node is of type Text. Are you sure it executed?

Comment: Yeah ive used Console to write a line, and it writes every 2 seconds.

Comment: Where you added Console.Write ? inside the case where `XmlNodeType.Text` ?

Comment: How do you check that StringValue remains "initial"?

Comment: Is the count variable a class or struct?

Comment: a variable, i check it by looking at it in the window the label is in. this is for an application